# Unable to change LabelStyle in LineLegend using SetOptions

Tags: legending

I am setting the "Times New Roman" font family for the label style in the `LineLegend` function in the following way, which doesn't work.

```
SetOptions[{LineLegend}, LabelStyle -> {14, Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}];
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image]

What works is only when I change the options manually when calling the function itself, (see below)

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", LabelStyle -> {14, Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}]]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `LabelStyle` of `Plot` gets piped into `LineLegend` probably to ensure a uniform font of ticks and labels per default. Setting the `LabelStyle` of `Plot` to `{14, Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}` results in a change of font style in the legend but also for the ticks. Other Options for `LineLegend` get inherited (like `LegendFunction`) with priority. You could also consider modifying the default for `PlotLegends` of `Plot`.